# Como añadir funcion de mostrar el ID del elemento pulsado, con la primer letra en mayuscula y borrando un caracter adicional en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una serie de botones con un ID predeterminado:

```
<input type="button" id="1alfa">
<input type="button" id="1beta">
<input type="button" id="1gamma">
<input type="button" id="1omega">
```

Tengo una función que se supone debería obtener el ID del botón y añadírselo como mensaje de alerta usando una función `onclick`.

```
function botones () {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var value = elements[i].id;
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
    var mensaje= "Sistema"+value[i];
    mensaje = mensaje.replace("1","");
    alert(mensaje);
    }
  }
}
```

El problema me muestra

> Sistema:undefined

Como puedo hacer que al pulsar cada boton el muestre su nombre, ejemplo:

```
Sistema: alfa - Sistema: beta.
```

**1ra NOTA:** me falto especificar borrar el 1 que tienen los IDs.

**2da NOTA:** me falto especificar que quiero la primera letra del Id del botón en mayúscula.

Comment: `var mensaje= "Sistema "+this.id;` aunque se podría simplificar un poco más su función.

Comment: Victor tu código es casí correcto, usa this.id en lugar de value[i] y asegura llamar tu botones() ,@Victor-Random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En cuanto a tu código original me parece que el problema es como se obtiene el id del elemento para mostrar el mensaje, en lugar de `value[i]` usa `this.id` , además asegura tu método botones() sea llamado para que agregue los respectivos listener:

```js
function botones() {   
 
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");  
  for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
   var value = elements[i].id;
  
   elements[i].onclick = function() {
      var mensaje= "Sistema: "+capitalizeReplaceText(''+this.id);         
      alert(mensaje);
    }
   
  }
 
}

//Reemplaza y convierte primera letra en mayuscula.
function capitalizeReplaceText(texto) {
  texto = texto.replace("1","");    
  return texto.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ texto.slice(1);
}
```

```html
<body onload="botones()">
<input type="button" id="1alfa" >
    <input type="button" id="1beta" >
    <input type="button" id="1gamma">
    <input type="button" id="1omega" >
```

---

Otra solución sencilla, sería enviar el id al método:

```js
function botones(clicked_id) {
  alert("Sistema: "+ capitalizeReplaceText(''+clicked_id));
}


//Reemplaza y convierte primera letra en mayuscula.
function capitalizeReplaceText(texto) {
  texto = texto.replace("1","");    
  return texto.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ texto.slice(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="1alfa" onclick="botones(this.id);">
<input type="button" id="1beta" onclick="botones(this.id);">
<input type="button" id="1gamma" onclick="botones(this.id);">
<input type="button" id="1omega" onclick="botones(this.id);">
```

---

Comment: **No olvidar el replace** , que el OP especifica .

Comment: @Dev.Joel donde amigo?

Comment: La respuesta es muy buena , pero el op también desea eliminar el **1** al inicio del _id_  clickeado , por eso realiza un `replace`

Comment: gracias, estoy editando además agregando una forma sin enviar el id

Comment: Oigan... **OP = Over Powered** xD jjajajaj @Dev.Joel

Comment: @Victor-Random eres el Over Powered! he editado la respuesta considerando tu código, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys si agrego otro elemento mas a la pregunta es valido?. revisa

Comment: @Victor-Random si claro!!! Listo.

Comment: @Jorgesys agrega un espacio ;) **Sistema: Alfa"

Answer (score 4):

Debes usar la palabra clave `this` que apunta al elemento asociado al evento, en tu caso apunta al `<input type="button"..>` donde se hizo **click**.

Ejemplo:

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
el.forEach(function(e) {
 e.onclick = function () {
  var mensaje= "Sistema: "+this.id.replace("1","");
  console.log(mensaje);
 }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="1alfa">
<input type="button" id="1beta">
<input type="button" id="1gamma">
<input type="button" id="1omega">
```

Comment: **No olvidar el replace** en su respuesta ;)

Comment: Listo!... Gracias @Dev.Joel!! ;))...

Answer (score 0):

```
function botones () {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
document.getElementById("registro").value=("Configurando: [Botones de Estado: "+elements.length+"]");
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
    var id= this.id.replace("1"," ");
    var mensaje= "Sistema: "+id;
    alert(id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ¿ Cuál sería el propósito de inicializar dos variables , `i` y `len` ? y no directamente en la condición `i< elements.length`?

Comment: @Dev.Joel tenia guardado ese codigo por alli y lo use xD, se ve mas ordenado :)

Comment: Mientras menos código escribas mas fácil sera entenderlo, eso incluye a las variables. ;))...